# Supabase raw_user_meta_data values stored with quotation marks (" ")

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql, supabase

I have a function in Supabase like this:

```
declare
  username text;
  name text;
begin

  insert into public.users (id, email, username, name, role)
values (new.id, new.email, new.raw_user_meta_data -> 'username', name = new.raw_user_meta_data -> 'name', 'student');

  return new;
end;
```

The function is used for inserting additional data into public.users table after Sign Up.

I tested the function by executing auth and send the body with Postman like this:

```
{
  "email": "tst@gmail.com",
  "password": "asdflk;jsadfkl;j",
  "data": {
    "username":"Tester",
    "name":"Tester number one"
  }
}
```

The data stored must be `Tester` and `Tester number one` right?

But the data I found in public.users table is `"Tester"` and `"Tester number one"`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`->` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) yields `json`/`jsonb`. Cast to `text`, it preserves the double-quotes. If you want `text` value out of the `raw_user_metda_data`, use `->>` instead. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/a_pT8aTc)

```
declare
  username text;
  name text;
begin

  insert into public.users (id, email, username, name, role)
values (new.id, new.email, new.raw_user_meta_data ->> 'username', name = new.raw_user_meta_data ->> 'name', 'student');

  return new;
end;
```

```
select ('{"email": "tst@gmail.com",
          "password": "asdflk;jsadfkl;j",
          "data": {
            "username":"Tester",
            "name":"Tester number one" }
         }'::jsonb->'data'->'username')::text as "jsonb cast to text";
```

| jsonb cast to text |
| --- |
| "Tester" |

```
select '{"email": "tst@gmail.com",
          "password": "asdflk;jsadfkl;j",
          "data": {
            "username":"Tester",
            "name":"Tester number one" }
         }'::jsonb->'data'->>'username' as "text extracted from jsonb";
```

| text extracted from jsonb |
| --- |
| Tester |